# Weird behavior with this and $scope in controller method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

Well, I am new to angular and my prior searches showed me that using 'this' is different from '$scope', inside a controller. Bearing that in mind, I decided to only use scope in my application, which brought me to this weird behavior I am trying to understand.

**Here is my controller and module:**

```
angular.module('dnd-dices',[]).controller('SingleDicerollCtrl',['$scope','DiceSet',SingleDicerollCtrl]);

function SingleDicerollCtrl($scope, DiceSet){
    $scope.dices = DiceSet;
    $scope.selectedDie = $scope.dices[0];

    $scope.roll = function(){
        $scope.result = Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.selectedDie.max) + 1 ;
    };
}
```

**here is my html:**

```
<select ng-options="die.label for die in dices track by die.label" ng-model="selectedDie">
</select>
<h>Result({{selectedDie.label}}):{{result}}</h>

<input type="button" ng-click="roll()" value="Roll!"/>
```

**Question point:**
When i call the **roll method**, the `$scope.selectedDice` variable is in it's original value (`$scope.selectedDie = $scope.dices[0];`), while `this.selectedDie` is changing according to my ng-model (presented in the html). Why is this happening and when should i use this or `$scope` inside a method?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: How do you know this.selectedDie is changing if you aren't using it?

Comment: The roll method uses it, and i was debugging it.. I'll edit my question with the result.  <h>Result({{selectedDie.label}}):{{result}}</h>